# Chinese Character get from URL turn into question mark

Tags: php

**My URL** : localhost/folder/file/`刀塔`

**Return URL** : localhost/folder/file/??

I using `$_GET['REQUEST_URI']` and get the return url.

Comment: Is all your encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: @miknik i got used before but nothing changed..

Comment: @miknik on website all chinese character display without problem.. only from url will turn to question marks.

Comment: How are you creating the URL, is it URL encoded?

Comment: @chris85 just normally put the value on the link

Comment: @TeohKoonTatt Urlencode it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php